# Trying to get a hold on this paper Fixpoint induction and proofs of program properties. D. PARK

Tags: reference-request, fixed-point-theorems, fixed-points

I am trying to get a hold on this paper

Fixpoint induction and proofs of program properties.  D. PARK

It was published in this journal (Machine Intelligence Volume 5)

https://www.doc.ic.ac.uk/~shm/MI/mi5.html

But I dont see how to get a hold of this journal or paper. Can someone please help.

Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

I finally found a scan of [the paper](https://www.yumpu.com/en/document/read/36543960/machine-intelligence-5-aitopics/69).